# Absolute value and $\varepsilon - \delta$ proofs of continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I am seriously struggling with $\varepsilon - \delta$ proofs overall continuity of a function (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815209/varepsilon-delta-proof-that-fx-x2-2-is-continuous-question-conc/1815291?noredirect=1#comment3709493_1815291) there is an attempt).

In the attempt to see how to prove the continuity of $f(x) = x^2 - 2$, I got to the point where I assume $\delta \leq 1$, and I proceed as follows:

> \begin{align*}
> | x - c | < 1 & \Longleftrightarrow -1 < x  - c < 1 \\
> & \Longleftrightarrow c-1 < x < c+1.
> \end{align*}
>
> If we add $c$ to the previous expression we obtain
>
> $$ 2c -1 < x + c <  2c + 1 \Longleftrightarrow | x + c | < 2c+1.$$

But this does not work, because I should get $2|c|+1$.

*What am I missing?*

I think I truly miss a basic understanding of how absolute value works in this context (plus some other things, but in this question I would focus on the absolute value issue).

Thanks a lot for your time as always.

Comment: Does it help to note that $2c+1<2|c|+1$?

Comment: Thanks, it does a lot! (Shame on me)

Comment: Decompose the last absolute value and see that the equality that you put isnt true.

Comment: *Should be a $\leq$, shame on me ;)

Comment: @Masacroso: Are you referring to mine inequality, or to Servaes' one?

Comment: @Kolmin you equality isn true i.e. $2c -1 < x + c <  2c + 1 $ is not equivalent to $| x + c | < 2c+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $c<0$, $c=-|c|$.  Then, for $c<0$, we have

$$-(2|c|+1)<x+c<(2|c|+1)$$

Hence, $|x+c|<|\,(2|c|+1)\,|$