# Determine that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x-6} \text{ in } x_0=3$ is continous with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of limit/criterion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

> [Proof-verification] Determining whether the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x-6} \text{ in } x_0=3$; $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is continous $\color{red}{\text{ in  }x_0}$ or not with the
>   $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of limit/criterion:

---

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x-6} \text{ in } x_0=3$$

Proof:
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and ${\mid x-x_0\mid}<\delta \iff {\mid x-3\mid}<\delta$

\begin{align}
{\mid f(x)-f(x_0)\mid}&= {\mid\sqrt{x^2-x-6}-\sqrt{3^2-3-6}\mid}\\
& ={\mid\sqrt{x^2-x-6}\mid}\\
& ={\mid\sqrt{x+2} \cdot \sqrt{x-3}\mid}\\
& <\sqrt{x+2}\cdot \sqrt{x+2}\\
& = x+2\\
& < x-3+5 \\
& <\delta+5 =: \varepsilon \\
& \iff \delta = \varepsilon -5
\end{align}

$\implies$ the function is continous in $x_0=3 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad_\blacksquare $

---

Is this proof correct?

Comment: So, if $\varepsilon = 1$, what's the $\delta > 0$?

Comment: @Ennar It wouldn't be positive

Comment: And that's not really good now, is it?

Comment: No, because $\delta$ needs to be positve, right?

Comment: Exactly.$\hphantom{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the function $f$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but for 
$$
x\in(-\infty,-2]\cup[3,+\infty).
$$

So one can only talk about its continuity of $f$ at $x=3$ from the right.

For $x>3$, you are right to get
$$
|f(x)-f(3)|=\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+2}.
$$
Note that you don't need the absolute value for the square root terms.

But then you made a mistake: the $\delta$ you get must be *positive*.

The term $\sqrt{x-3}$ should not be dropped and it would give you the desired $\delta$.

Consider instead for $0<x-3<1$ the inequality
$$
\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+2}\leq 6\sqrt{x-3}\le\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Can you explain more in detail how you came to this conclusion and the estimation upwards? $\Big($Consider instead for $0<x-3<1$ the inequality $\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+2}\leq 6\sqrt{x-3}\le\varepsilon\Big)$.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+2}\leq 6\sqrt{x-3}$? With your hint I would come to the following conclusion: $\cdots \leq 6 \cdot \sqrt{x-3} < 6 \sqrt{ \delta }=: \varepsilon \implies \delta = \dfrac{\varepsilon^2}{36}$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Doesbaddel: If $0<x-3<1$, then $3<x<4$ and thus $\sqrt{x+2}<\sqrt{6}<6$. I just did a rough estimate.

Comment: @Doesbaddel: you would need $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon^2}{36}\}$.

Comment: Why does $x-3$ needs to be between $0$ and $1$? Where does this step come from? Why do you need $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon^2}{36}\}$ and not $\delta= \frac{\varepsilon^2}{36}$? (Otherwise, your estimation makes sense now and I understood it.)

Comment: Note that eventually, you want $x$ to be such that $0<x-3<\delta$. The positive number $1$ is an arbitrarily chosen positive number so that one can have a bound for $\sqrt{x+3}$. Note also that in order to prove continuity at $3$, one needs only to consider the $x$ "near 3". On the other hand, you need $\delta \leqslant 1$ so that whenever you have $0<x-3<\delta$, you have $0<x-3<1$ as well.

Comment: This similar problem (and its answers) may be useful for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1815209/587192

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. However, in this task I don't need to show that the function $f(x)$ is continous for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I only need to show, that $f(x)$ is continous in $x_0=3$. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Doesbaddel True. But instead of $0<|x-3|<\delta$, you need $0<x-3<\delta$, since $f$ is *not* defined for $-2<x<3$.

Comment: Oh, I finally understood it. Thanks.